# my function in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote this bash script. also l wrote my function with param. 
function is called with no parameters normally. the parameters sampled several ways, but nothing of them has been successful

```
#!/bin/bash
   RESULT_DIR="./imgR"
   rm -r $RESULT_DIR
   mkdir $RESULT_DIR
   widthOrigin=0
   heightOrigin=0
   widthR=0
   heightR=0
   for i in ~/img/{*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.JPG,*.JPEG,*.PNG}   
   do
   echo  "file" $i
   if [ -f $i ]
   then 
   echo "file1" 
   widthOrigin=`identify -format "%w" $i`
   #$checkTwo
   widthR=$(checkTwo $widthOrigin)
   heightOrigin=`identify -format "%h" $i`
   #heightR=$(checkTwo $heightOrigin)

   echo "width origin" $widthOrigin " width power 2" $widthR
   echo "height origin" $heightOrigin "wicth power 2" $heightR

   #convert -resize $widthR $heightR $i $RESULT_DIR/$(basename "$i") 
   fi
   done
   exit 0
```

and my function

```
   checkTwo(){
   echo "checkTwo"
   param=$1
   echo "param" $param
   if [ param -ge "1024"]
   then
   return 1024
   else

   if [param -ge "512"]
   then 
   return "512"
   else

   if [param -ge "256"]
   then
   return "256"
   else

   if [param -ge "64"]
   then
   return "64"
   else

   if [param -ge "32"]
   then
   return "32"
   else

   if [param -ge "16"]
   then 
   return "16"

   else
   if [param -ge "4"]
   return "4"
   else
   return "2"

   fi fi fi fi fi  fi  fi   
   }
   }
   #end
```

but in  line  "   widthR=$(checkTwo $widthOrigin)" l have error "function widthOrigin not found"

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if [ "$param" -ge "1024" ]
```

You need a dollar sign before the variable name for it to be expanded. And you need spaces around `[` and `]`. The quotes around `$param` are needed to avoid a problem if the parameter is empty or contains whitespace.

Another problem: The function should use `echo`, not `return`, since you're using it in `$(...)`, which substitutes the stdout of the function.

You also don't need all those nested `if`s, with a zillion `fi`s at the end, if you use `elif` between the cases instead of `else if`.

```
if ...
then ...
elif ...
then ...
elif ...
then ...
else ...
fi
```

I can't explain why you're getting the specific error you're getting, since there's no reference to a function `widthOrigin`.

Actually I'd implement that whole function as a loop:

```
x=1024
while [ "$param" -lt $x ] && [ $x -gt 2 ]
do
    x=((x>>1))
done
echo $x
```

Comment: But problem in call function. If I use
   checkTwo $widthOrigin - I have error "comand not found"

Comment: You seem to have an extra `}` after the end of the function, although I don't think that should cause a problem like that. Is the function definition in the same script as the caller?